# Masking \end{lstlisting}

Tags: listings, environments

I am not sure if I am using the right wording in title. Basically what I need is to add the following source using the listing package.

In preamble:

```
\usepackage{listings}
```

then and is here when I have the problem:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
     \begin{lstlisting}
     \end{lstlisting} 
\end{lstlisting}
```

but I am getting `Package Listings Error: Extra \endlstlisting`.

How can I "mask" the first `\end{lstlisting}`? I've been through the documentation but I am lost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to show examples of `lstlisting` itself, define a different environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{TeXlstlisting}{\lstset{language=[LaTeX]TeX}}{}
```

Then

```
\begin{TeXlstlisting}
  \begin{lstlisting}
  ...
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{TeXlstlisting}
```

will work. This strategy can be useful also when one has to manage listings in two or more programming languages.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `mathescape=true` option to a listing to escape to math but do nothing, tricking [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) into breaking the control sequence *anywhere* into two distinct components. In the MWE below I used `\$$end{lstlisting}`, breaking it up into `\` and `end{lstlisting}`; the first `$` opens and escapes to math mode, while the second `$` closes math mode and returns to the listing. `listings` recognizes the control sequence `\end{lstlisting}` as the ending otherwise.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listing
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[mathescape=true]
  \begin{lstlisting}
    Hello world!
  \$$end{lstlisting}
​\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: This leave a `$` at the end of the listing.

Comment: `listings` processes the combination `$$` correctly in my output, with `listings 2007/02/22 1.4`.

Comment: Interesting as I have the exact same listings package version.  I updated everything yesterday so perhaps something else is different.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can nest within the `lstlisting` environment. Since this is a verbatin environment, the second `\begin{lstlisting}` is ignored, and the first `\end{lstlisting}` results in the termination of the outer `\begin{lstlisting}` leaving an extra `\end{lstlisting}`.

If you provide more details on exactly what you want to do, perhaps we can provide a way to accomplish that.

If all you want to do is to show the LaTeX output using the `listings` environment, I'd use [the `showexpl` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/showexpl):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showexpl}

\lstdefinestyle{demoLatexStyle}{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, stepnumber=2, numbersep=5pt,
    frame=none,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,% print whole listing small
}
\lstloadlanguages{[LaTeX]TeX}

\begin{document}
\begin{LTXexample}[pos=b,style=demoLatexStyle]
     \begin{lstlisting}
        blah blah
     \end{lstlisting} 
\end{LTXexample}
\enddocument}
```