# Rewrite \begin{foo}\end{foo} to \begin{bar}{opts}\end{bar}?

Tags: macros, listings, verbatim, minted

I know this is likely a simple Latex macro question. I've got a large document with a ton of `lstlisting` blocks, and I'd like to use `minted` instead.

That means turning blocks that look like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
  ...code...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Into something that looks like this:

```
\begin{minted}{scala}
  ...code...
\end{minted}
```

I know I can do a find/replace but want an excuse to figure out how to write some of my own LaTeX macros :)

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Generally this would be easy but your problem here is going to be that these are verbatim-like environments so you normally need _exactly_ the closing text to be in the source.

Comment: And in a certain sense, I wouldn't want to obscure a LaTeX document like that -- there are plenty of other ways to get your hands dirty in macro programming :)

Comment: @Sean Allred, I have a several hundred page document that I just want to test out minted on. I don't want to do a find/replace all lstlsting blocks just to look at it afterwards and decide – meh, nevermind. So it seemed like a little macro would help me at least see how minted looks.

Comment: @JosephWright, I don't follow – I have a big document that already compiles with the closing text in place. Could you elaborate just a bit further?

Comment: @HeatherMiller Consider something like `sed`, then -- basic tool in the kit: `sed 's/{lstlsting}/{minted}{scala}/' file.tex > minted-test.tex`. Make a backup though, just in case -- I haven't tested that command. What Joseph means is that verbatim environments (like `{lstlisting}` and `{minted}`) look for *exactly* the text `\end{lstlisting}` (or `\end{minted}`) to stop the environment. The normal way environments are ended is a bit simpler, so making it a macro isn't a problem. Something like this though would be much more involved, if not infeasible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `\newminted` command

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}

\newminted[lstlisting]{scala}{}

\begin{document}



\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
/* Block
 * comment */

int main()
{
    int i;

    // Line comment.
    puts("Hello world!");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
    }

    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well how about that. I guess this is akin to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31980/17423 after all :)

Comment: @SeanAllred I am not sure, if i understand this is another thing

Comment: Well, it's the same idea as `\lstnewlisting`, but implemented with `minted` :) (I'm not saying this is a dupe, for the record -- just pointing out the parallels.)

Comment: @SeanAllred ok i think you're write and that's what i was pointing