# Is it possible to include a lstlisting code block inside an lstlisting?

Tags: listings, environments

I am trying to include a LaTeX code within an `lstlisting`. But the problem is that the LaTeX code includes an `lstlisting`, so the `\end{lstlisting}` within the included code is terminating the actual `lstlisting`. Is there some way to make the compiler not take that as the actual environment end.

```
\lstset {
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    language=TeX,
    frame=single,
    backgroundcolor=\color{grey},
    columns=fullflexible
}
..
\begin{document}
    ..
    \begin{lstlisting}
        % The lstlisting can be used as follows
        \begin{lstlisting}
            % Your code goes here
        \end{lstlisting} % This example end-statement is terminating the actual listing
    \end{lstlisting}
    ..
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Found a solution at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31980/masking-endlstlisting?rq=1. Marking this as a duplicate